# Three-way tables with survey or srvyr

Tags: r, survey

I am using the 2015 BRFSS data to mimic this example [this example](http://thomasyokota.com/blog/complex-survey-brfss/). Getting the diabetes prevalence, etc. works with `group_by()` as shown in Yakota's code. However, what if I need for each state, diabetes prevalence by race?

Comment: Would you mind putting some effort into your question by sharing example data, code and expected output? That, instead of linking blog posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you want

```
svyby(
  ~ diabetes_yes_no_variable , 
  ~ state_variable + race_variable , 
  your_survey_design , 
  svymean 
)
```